# copying folder from source to destination in build.xml using copydir command

Tags: ant, build

I am facing issue while copying directories from source to destination in ant build file.

code:-

```
<target name="getResources" depends="init">
    <delete dir="${resources.dir}"/>    
    <copy file="${svn.resources.url}" tofile="${resources.dir} " />
</target>
```

Error:-

```
build.xml:150: Use a resource collection to copy directories.
```

Please suggest me how to copy directory from source to destination. I used several ways...like

`<export srcUrl="" destPath="">` this is also saying deprecated and used  and  also. but none of the properties are working. Please suggest me how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!-- copy one file -->
<copy file="/home/guest/workspace/so/src/build.xml" tofile="/home/guest/workspace/so/src/build2.xml" />

<!-- copy a folder recuresively -->
<copy todir="/home/guest/workspace/so/src2">
    <fileset dir="/home/guest/workspace/so/src" includes="**" />
</copy>
```

you also may want to look at copy task documentation and examples [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)